# Why my code doesn't run ? Insertion Sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, insertion-sort

Function of insertion sort is not working, Error is : **A function is taking too long to run. Perhaps you have a mistake in your code?**

```
// this function
var insert = function(array, rightIndex, value) {
    for(var j = rightIndex;
        j >= 0 && array[j] > value;
        j--) 
    {
        array[j + 1] = array[j];
    }   
    array[j + 1] = value; 
};

var insertionSort = function(array) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length ; i++)
    {
        insert(array,i,array[i+1]);
    }
};

var array = [22, 11, 99, 88, 9, 7, 42];
insertionSort(array);
println("Array after sorting:  " + array);
Program.assertEqual(array, [7, 9, 11, 22, 42, 88, 99]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var insert = function(array, rightIndex, value) {
    for(var j = rightIndex;
        j >= 0 && array[j] > value;
        j--) 
    {
        array[j + 1] = array[j];
    }   
    array[j + 1] = value; 
};

var insertionSort = function(array) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length - 1 ; i++)
    {
        insert(array,i,array[i+1]);
    }
};

var array = [22, 11, 99, 88, 9, 7, 42];
insertionSort(array);
console.log(array);
```

you should run your loop 1 less iteration as you are calling the insert() function with i + 1;

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is on choosing array position as `[i+1]` and `[j+1]`

change

```
var insert = function(array, rightIndex, value) {
    for(var j = rightIndex;
        j >= 0 && array[j] > value;
        j--) 
    {
        array[j + 1] = array[j];
    }   
    array[j + 1] = value; 
};
```

into

```
var insert = function(array, rightIndex, value) {
    for(var j = rightIndex;
            j > 0 && array[j-1] > value;
            j--) 
        {
            array[j] = array[j-1];
        }   
        array[j] = value; 
    };
```

and

```
 insert(array, i, array[i+1]);
```

into

```
 insert(array, i, array[i]);
```

Comment: Might be worth explaining why this change is necessary. As no-one will learn from this answer

Comment: By `array[i+1]` we cant be sure if there is `i+1`th element

Comment: Question is to set the insertionSort  function not the insert,
Although after implement this change Error remain same

Answer (score 0):

Try going through the array backwards inside the insertionSort function:

```
var insertionSort = function(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    insert(array,i,array[i+1]); 
  } 
};
```